# Anno 2205: How to build a Desalinization Plant?

Tags: anno-2205

I have just bought a game named Anno 2205, set basics like minimum difficulty and started a new game.

The problem is I shall build a [Desalinization Plant](http://anno2205.wikia.com/wiki/Desalinization_Plant), but it requires [Coastal Building Site](http://anno2205.wikia.com/wiki/Coastal_Building_Site) and I can't figure out literally in several hours as to where I can find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There are only handful of designated areas throughout the islands for this purpose. Suffice to say, I shall look better around next time. Their number is truly limited.